# Media Foundation IMFMediaSource::CreatePresentationDescriptor invocation never ends

Tags: audio, com, directx, ms-media-foundation

I'm triying to use Media Foundation to play mp3 file and I have a problem getting `PresentationDesctiptor` using `CreatePresentationDescriptor` method

What am I doing:

- Start MF using `MFStartup`
- Create session using `MFCreateMediaSession`
- Create SourceResolver using `MFCreateSourceResolver`
- Create MediaSource using `CreateObjectFromURL` from SourceResolver
- Create topology using `MFCreateTopology`
- Trying to create PresentationDescriptor using `CreatePresentationDescriptor` from MediaSource

When I call `CreatePresentationDescriptor` no error/exception occurs it just stands there and does nothing. When I pause Visual Strudio it indicates that program is still waiting for method to finish. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Maybe it'll help if you used Microsoft's sample code to play mp3s. I used their sample to play my game's background music. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Media-engine-sample-0bd96b86  (copy and pasted the files MediaEnginePlayer.h/.cpp into my project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not metion that I use C# for this (did not think this was relevant)

The problem was that when importing com interfaces in C# you need to import all methods of interface not only those that are called. Some methods can call not imported methods and cause Access Violation that is not reported to Visual Strudio debugger and as a result it seems like method is never finished invokink.